# How to get the selected values on the server side when using Bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I submit my form, I can see form data being submitted like such:

```
genre[]:action
genre[]:thriller
genre[]:romance
```

On the server side when I retrieve `genre[]` from request, I only get one value.

I did everything they said in [this page](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#post), but it is not working

Here is my code:

```html
<select class="select " name="genre[]" id="genre" multiple="multiple" >
    <% for(Param param:selectGenres) {%>
    <option value="<%=param.getValue() %>"  
     <%=param.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(genre)?"selected":"" %> ><%=param.getTitle() %></option>                              
    <%} %>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#genre').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 300,
        buttonWidth: '99%',
        checkboxName:"genre[]"

    });
});
```

server side:

```
request.getParameter("genre[]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle array of parameters, you need to use javax.servlet.ServletRequest#getParameterValues.

So your code a the server side might be:

```
final String[] genres = request.getParameterValues("genre[]");
```